# How to get the image file?

Tags: html, ruby, heroku

I have put my ruby code in heroku. The problem is, i have a form and it has browse button to get the image from user. When clicking on browse it shows the window to choose and after choosing it looks for the image in server and not in the users system. How to make it look at users system for getting the image and store in tmp folder in heroku?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" >
```

Comment: could you paste form code and code where image is saved

Comment: '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
            writer << '<label for="file">Filename:</label>'
            writer << '<input type="file" name="file" id="file" > '     I just used this

Comment: Reedit your question and paste the code there so it's formatted.

Comment: @user1409314: you don't save image, instead upload image and save its path in db. Try one of the gem to upload image `paperclip` is good for uploading.

Comment: Ok. Instead of saving the path in db is it possible to get the path so that i can specify the path of the image in :venue_image => StorageRoom::Image.new_with_filename(path), which posts the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it'll be much easier for you to use the very good [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/) than to reinvent the wheel on this one.